# Get current value / content of all children, <input /> and <span>, of <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="setence">
<select id="spellingSuggestions"> 
    <option class="0" value="teh">teh</option> 
    <option class="1" value="the">the</option> 
    <option class="2" value="Te">Te</option> 
    <option class="3" value="tech">tech</option> 
    <option class="4" value="Th">Th</option> 
    <option class="5" value="eh">eh</option> 
</select> 
<select id="spellingSuggestions"> 
    <option class="0" value="wuick">wuick</option> 
    <option class="1" value="quick">quick</option> 
    <option class="2" value="wick">wick</option> 
    <option class="3" value="Vick">Vick</option> 
    <option class="4" value="Buick">Buick</option> 
    <option class="5" value="whack">whack</option> 
</select> 
<span class="correctWord">brown</span>
<select id="spellingSuggestions"> 
    <option class="0" value="fx">fx</option> 
    <option class="1" value="Fax">Fax</option> 
    <option class="2" value="Fox">Fox</option> 
    <option class="3" value="fax">fax</option> 
    <option class="4" value="fix">fix</option> 
    <option class="5" value="fox">fox</option> 
</select> 
<span class="correctWord">jumped</span>
<span class="correctWord">over</span>
<select id="spellingSuggestions"> 
    <option class="0" value="teh">teh</option> 
    <option class="1" value="the">the</option> 
    <option class="2" value="Te">Te</option> 
    <option class="3" value="tech">tech</option> 
    <option class="4" value="Th">Th</option> 
    <option class="5" value="eh">eh</option> 
</select> 
<select id="spellingSuggestions"> 
    <option class="0" value="lzy">lzy</option> 
    <option class="1" value="lazy">lazy</option> 
    <option class="2" value="Ly">Ly</option> 
    <option class="3" value="Lay">Lay</option> 
    <option class="4" value="Loy">Loy</option> 
    <option class="5" value="lay">lay</option> 
</select> 
<span class="correctWord">dog</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the content / value of each of the spans and the second `<option>` (.1) in each `<select>` in order and store it in a variable.

The string I am trying to get in the variable in this case is "the quick brown Fax jumped over teh lazy dog"

In pseudo-code, I would:

- Iterate through all of the children of #sentence
- Check if the current child element is of class .correctWord or not.
- If it is, get the content of it.
- If not, get the value of the its second child.
- stitch the content and values together in order
- Store newly composed string in var

How can I do this with javascript / jQuery ?

Comment: You have done pretty good with the psuedo code.. Any code ?

Comment: @Sushanth-- No code yet, I can't figure out the iterating through the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "";
$('#sentence').children().each(function(){
    if($(this).is('.correctWord')){
      str += " "+$(this).text();
    }else if($(this).is('select')){
     str += " "+$(this).find('option').eq(1).val();
    }
})
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/8juVe/